# How to copy a folder (divide into sub folders) using Python?

Tags: python, copy-paste

i try to copy a directory (divided into folders and subfolders) to a new folder that will be created.i work with python 2.7.

- dir_src = an exist folder
- dir_dst = a new folder (not exist) that all the folders will be copied to

I read https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html and tried this code:

```
import os,shutil

dir_src = r"C:\Project\layers"
dir_dst = r"C:\Project\new" 
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    print file 
    src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
    shutil.copytree(src_file, dst_file,symlinks=False, ignore=None)
    print 'copytree'
```

But i get an error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 267] : 'C:\\Project\\layers\\abc.cpg/*.*'
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Seems like you do not have the permissions to read these files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About edited question and error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 267] : 'C:\\Project\\layers\\abc.cpg/*.*'
```

Please carefully read [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

```
import shutil

dir_src = r"C:\Project\layers"
dir_dst = r"C:\Project\new" 
shutil.copytree(dir_src, dir_dst)
```

you not need any for.

Note:
  Please keep in mind, that destination path shouldn't be existed.

Comment: Reishin, i must get a list of the folders and files that have been copied.

Comment: @newGIS nothing mentioned about that in the question. IF you need to log every file, consider to copy each file manually using recursion for a folders. And yes, `copytree` have no callback to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting (`Permission denied`) should tell you what is the problem - you don't have rights to read or copy the files. Running the program as administrator should fix it.